How to correctly paginate a SwiftUI view for PDF generation when content exceeds one page?
I'm generating PDFs from a SwiftUI view representing an invoice using ImageRenderer. The content flows perfectly on a single page, but multi-page content reverses order: the top of the view for the second page appears at the bottom of the first.
I try in the first time this answer but that not succeed : Algorithme try
I expected the content to flow from the first to the second page seamlessly. Instead, the pagination reverses the content order, disrupting readability.
struct PDFBodyView : View {
    let data : PDFModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            // Element in my view
        }
        .font(.callout)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
        .padding()
        .background(
            .windowBackground
        )
    }
}


@MainActor
    func renderView() -> URL? {
        guard let directory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else {
            return nil
        }
        let url = directory
            .appendingPathComponent("MyPDF")
            .appendingPathExtension(for: .pdf)
        
        let view = PDFBodyView(data: documentData)
        let renderer = ImageRenderer(content: view)
        
        renderer.render { size, renderer in
            var pageSize = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 600, height: 800)
            var currentPageY: CGFloat = 0
            let totalHeight = size.height
            
            guard let consumer = CGDataConsumer(url: url as CFURL),
                  let pdfContext =  CGContext(consumer: consumer,
                                              mediaBox: &pageSize, nil)
            else {
                return
            }
            
            while currentPageY < totalHeight {
                pdfContext.beginPDFPage(nil) // Starts a new page
                pdfContext.saveGState()
                
                
                // Move the context up by 'currentPageY'
                let horizontalTranslation = (pageSize.width - size.width) / 2
                let verticalTranslation = -currentPageY
                
                pdfContext.translateBy(
                    x: horizontalTranslation,
                    y: verticalTranslation
                )
                
                renderer(pdfContext) // Draw the content starting from 'currentPageY'
                
                pdfContext.restoreGState()
                pdfContext.endPDFPage() // Ends the current page
                
                currentPageY += pageSize.height // Move to the next page height
            }
            
            pdfContext.closePDF() // Finished with the PDF
        }
        
        return url
    }

And glitch like this :
First Page of the PDFView
Second Page of the PDFView

Please post a minimum reproducible example so others can help you. Your code is missing definitions for PDFModel and documentData.
